# How do I switch an Entity Setup from vertical to horizontal tabs?

Tags: c#, tabs, navigation, enterprise-web-library

I can never remember if I have to implement an interface on the page or the info, or if I have to override something. I want it here so I don't have to dig up an old solution. Also, is this information available anywhere in EWL comments or on the EWL web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `TabModeOverrider` from your entity setup's `Info` class:

```
partial class Info: TabModeOverrider {
    TabMode TabModeOverrider.GetTabMode() {
        return TabMode.Horizontal;
    }
}
```

I don't think this is documented anywhere else right now.